# Trying to Upload Images on Server using Webclient

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save my images using weblclient Object.

Here it is my code..

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("****", "*****");
    Uri addy = new Uri(@"\\104.199.191.5\Images\");

    client.Credentials = nc;
    byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, "Post", @"E:\free-html-admin-templates.JPG");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Right now I am getting error Network path not found..

Where am I wrong ??

Comment: is \\104.199.191.5\Images\  accessible on the server? Using the credentials you are passing in?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access some file share (\\104.199.191.5), not HTTP server. `WebClient ` is intended to communicate with HTTP servers.

Comment: so i may have to save my images on different server..not server.mappath???